# Knockout - Variable Value contains function body

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I try to access the values of the newly created elements, I get the function body as the variable values.

In the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr7Z4/6/),

1. Click "Add Name"
2. Enter First Name as "Kate" in the newly added row.
3. Click "Show All Names" button.

In the popup, function body gets displayed instead of "Kate". I am able to use the first element using `name.FirstName` and the rest of the elements using `name.FirstName()`.

***Is there any consistent way to get the value of `FirstName`in this scenario (across the loop iterations)?***

My HTML code is:

```
    <table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: names">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>First Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="value: FirstName" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Last Name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="value: LastName" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: addName">Add Name</button>
<button data-bind="click: showAllNames">Show All Names</button>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var namesArray = [{
    "FirstName": "Tom",
        "LastName": "Langdon"
}];

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.names = ko.observableArray(namesArray);

    self.CreateBlankName = function () {
        return {
            FirstName: ko.observable(""),
            LastName: ko.observable("")
        };
    };

    self.addName = function () {
        names.push(CreateBlankName());
    };

    self.showAllNames = function () {
        var namestring = "";
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.names(), function (name) {
            namestring += name.FirstName + "\n";
        });
        alert(namestring);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fisrtname` and `lastName` fields should be observables because you can changed through the UI.

So you need to turn these into ko.observables as follow :

```
var namesArray = [{
    "FirstName": ko.observable("Tom"),
    "LastName": ko.observable("Langdon")
}];
```

Now items will only have observables. That's why you need to change the `showAllNames`  function :

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.names(), function (name) {
    namestring += name.FirstName() + "\n";
});
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr7Z4/7/)

You can also *automatically* convert raw js object into observables object by using [ko.mapping.fromJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#example-using-komapping) function

Comment: Excellent answer. Just what I was looking for!!. Now, I understand that I can declare observables within JSON itself.